# New to coding having problems getting a output from this code

Tags: java

I keep getting 0 as an output for taxRate and amount of taxes paid when I need to be getting a value back. the tax rate is 15% of the gross profit which makes the amt of taxes paid gross profit times tax rate.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProfitProjection{

    double totalSales;
    double profitMargin;
    double projectedtotalSales;
    double grossProfit;
    double taxRate;
    double taxPaid;
    double netProfit;

    Scanner dataIn=new Scanner (System.in);

    public ProfitProjection(){

        System.out.print("Enter projected amount of total sales:");
        totalSales=dataIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the profit margin:");
        profitMargin=dataIn.nextDouble();

        taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;       
        grossProfit = totalSales * profitMargin;
        netProfit = grossProfit - taxRate;
        taxPaid = grossProfit * taxRate;



        System.out.println("Projected total sales:" + totalSales);
        System.out.println("Profit margin:" + profitMargin);
        System.out.println("Estimated gross profit:" + grossProfit);
        System.out.println("Tax rate:" + taxRate);
        System.out.println("Amount of tax paid:" + taxPaid);
        System.out.println("Estimated net profit:" + netProfit);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        new ProfitProjection();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not setting `grossProfit` anywhere.

Comment: `(0 * anything)` is 0.

Comment: look at your `grossProfit`.

Comment: He set `grossProfit`. He declared it as a `double`, then sets it to `totalSales * profitMargin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the calculations in the wrong order.

1. You use the value of `grossProfit` to calculate `taxRate`
2. You calculate the value for `grossProfit`.

The problem is that in the first step, where you haven't yet calculated the real `grossProfit` value, its value will be `0.0`.  This is due to Java's default initialization rule which applies to all fields of a class.

> If a field is not explicitly initialized, or you can (somehow) see its
>   value before explicit initialization takes places, then you will see
>   the default initial value.
>
> - `false` for a `boolean`,
> - zero for any other primitive type,
> - `null` for any reference type.

In short, you did the calculations in the wrong order.

Solution: change the order of those two statements ... and check that you haven't made the same mistake elsewhere.

---

In fact, there is another important mistake (maybe) ... that lead to this one not being detected.

You declared those variables as instance fields.  Given the code that written so far, they could have been declared as local variables.  If you had done that then the compiler would have told you that `grossProfit` is being used before it has been initialized.

I say this is **maybe** a mistake because it depends on whether there is more code / functionality that needs to be added later.

---

There are a couple of other errors:

- The `taxRate` variable is misnamed.  The tax rate is 0.015f.  What that variable contains is the actual tax payable,  not the tax rate.
- You should specify the tax rate as accurately as possible.  Use `0.015`, not `0.015f`.  The eff form is a `float` literal not a `double` literal.

Answer (score 2):

You only declared `grossProfit` without assigning any value to it, be default it is `0.0`

```
public ProfitProjection(){
    grossProfit = 1.0; // assign value to it in your constructor
    taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;       
}
```

Comment: He set `grossProfit`. He declared it as a `double`, then sets it to `totalSales * profitMargin`

Comment: @JoshHeaps that's after `taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;`  OP said he always got 0 for `taxRate`

Comment: @JoshHeaps  my updated edit was adding `taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;`  which can help you understand this answer better.

Comment: S.O. guidelines clearly say to state your edits clearly and why you are making them.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

`taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;`

You never initialized `grossProfit`, but only declared it. Thus, the value is being treated as 0 and thus `taxRate` is getting set to 0.

Comment: He set `grossProfit`. He declared it as a `double`, then sets it to `totalSales * profitMargin`

Comment: @JoshHeaps OP set it after using it the line before.

Comment: Yes, yes he did. I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What your problem is is that you are not setting gross profit before you set taxRate. So what the above answers are saying is slightly true, but not 100% I'll show you:

```
public class ProfitProjection{

double totalSales;
double profitMargin;
double projectedtotalSales;
double grossProfit;
double taxRate;
double taxPaid;
double netProfit;

Scanner dataIn=new Scanner (System.in);

public ProfitProjection(){

System.out.print("Enter projected amount of total sales:");
totalSales=dataIn.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the profit margin:");
profitMargin=dataIn.nextDouble();

grossProfit = totalSales * profitMargin; //Swapped this line
taxRate = grossProfit * .15f;       //With this line to have grossProfit set at a value before multiplication.
netProfit = grossProfit - taxRate;
taxPaid = grossProfit * taxRate;



    System.out.println("Projected total sales:" + totalSales);
    System.out.println("Profit margin:" + profitMargin);
    System.out.println("Estimated gross profit:" + grossProfit);
    System.out.println("Tax rate:" + taxRate);
    System.out.println("Amount of tax paid:" + taxPaid);
    System.out.println("Estimated net profit:" + netProfit);

}
public static void main(String args[]){

    new ProfitProjection();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:
The change I made in the code above is I swapped the setting of grossProfit, and the setting of taxRate. I also added comments onto those lines.

Comment: As the S.O. guide says, please leave comments so the answer may be improved.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but apprently your answer is not clear for downvoters. It is hard for me to understand what you have modified

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, it helped me understand my problem and now it outputs the correct values thanks.